# How can i change the button variant when button is selected in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have created the Map<String,List> which we have created in the Javascript and displayed in lightning button. Now I am clicking on the button, variant is not getting updated. How can I change the variant?

**Creation of the Map Code**

```
this.actionUtilClass.executeAction(params).then(response => { 
            this.productCustom = response.result.IPResult;
            this.monthlyPrice = this.productCustom.LiabilityMonthlyPrice;
            this.yearlyPrice = this.productCustom.LiabilityYearlyPrice;
            this.defualtAttValue = false;
            var attributeName = '';
            let newStructure = [];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productCustom));
            
            this.monthlyVariant = 'brand';
            this.yearlyVariant = 'neutral';
    
            this.showMonthlyData = true;
            this.showYearlyData = false;
            this.showError = true;
            this.mapDataKey = 'attlabel.label'+'-'+'attValue';
            
            let mapAttData = new Map();
            let mapKeyBrand = new Map();
    
            let today = new Date();
            this.defualtDate = today.toISOString();
            let mapNewData = new Map();
            this.productCustom.Attribute.forEach(newData=>{
        
                let attribute = newData;
                let label = attribute.AttributeLabel;
                let value = newData;
                let defualtValue = attribute.AttributeDefaultValue
                
                if(mapAttData.has(label)){
                    let values = mapAttData.get(label);
                    if(newData.ProductAttributeValue == newData.AttributeDefaultValue){
                        value.ButtonVariant = 'brand';
                    }else{
                        value.ButtonVariant = 'neutral';
                    }
                    values.push(value);
                    mapAttData.set(label,values);
    
                }else{
                    //console.log('Values',value[]);
                    let values = [value];
                    mapAttData.set(label, values);
                }
            })
            
           
            mapAttData.forEach((values, label) => {
                this.structuredData.push({ label: label, values: values });
            });
```

**Click on the button**

```
handleClick(event){
    const dataValue =  event.target.value;
    
   this.structuredData.forEach((value, key) => {
        console.log(value.values.ProductAttributeValue);
        if(value.values.ProductAttributeValue == dataValue){
            console.log('In If');
            value.ButtonVariant = 'brand';
        }else{
            value.ButtonVariant = 'neutral';
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML Code for Displaying the button**

```
<table style="margin-left:5%">
            <template for:each={structuredData} for:item="attLabel">
                <tr key={attLabel.label}>
                    <td><lightning-formatted-text value={attLabel.label} style="color: #191919;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;letter-spacing: 0;line-height: 21px;"></lightning-formatted-text><lightning-helptext class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg" content="Product Attributes"></lightning-helptext></td>
                </tr>
            <lightning-button-group key={attLabel}> 
                <template for:each={attLabel.values} for:item="attValue">
                    <td key={attValue.ProductAttributeValue}>
                            <lightning-button label={attValue.ProductAttributeLabel} variant={attValue.ButtonVariant} onclick={handleClick} value={attValue.ProductAttributeValue}></lightning-button></td>
                </template>
            </lightning-button-group> 
            </template>
        </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific reason behind it not working

but you could use -

```
 event.target.variant='neutral'
```

To make it more dynamic you can set data-id in the button -

```
<lightning-button data-id={attValue.dataId} label={attValue.ProductAttributeLabel} variant={attValue.buttonVariant} onclick={handleClick} value={attValue.ProductAttributeValue}></lightning-button>
```

```
structuredData = [
        {

            label: 11,
            values: [
                {
                    ProductAttributeValue: '1',
                    buttonVariant: 'brand',
                    ProductAttributeLabel: 'child',
                    dataId: 'buttonOne'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


if(value.values.ProductAttributeValue == dataValue){
 console.log('In If');
 const btn= this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${value.dataId}"]`);
 btn.variant = 'success';
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the ProductAtrributeValue in console. It is coming as a undefined

Comment: I have added the JSON structure as well @Mukul

Comment: try this - value.values[0].ProductAttributeValue

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields) (emphasis mine):

> Changes are detected when a new value is assigned to the field by comparing the value identity using ===. This works well for primitive types like numbers or boolean.
> **When manipulating complex types like objects and arrays, you must create a new object and assign it to the field for the change to be detected**.

In order to trigger a rerender you should change the reference hold by `structuredData`. The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) is what you're looking for.

Moreover in handleClick method `value.values` is an array, so it doesn't hold a property `ProductAttributeValue`, but its elements do:

```js
handleClick(event){
    const dataValue =  event.target.value;

    this.structuredData.forEach((value) => {
        for (const btn of value.values) {
            console.log(btn.ProductAttributeValue);
            if(btn.ProductAttributeValue == dataValue){
                console.log('In If');
                btn.ButtonVariant = 'brand';
            }else{
                btn.ButtonVariant = 'neutral';
            }
        }
    });
    // create a new array
    this.structuredData = [...this.structuredData];
}
```

Comment: Hi @RubenDG, I am getting the console.log as a undefined.

Comment: Hi @ShantanuMahajan, I updated the answer